# setOnItemClickListner not working with StickeyHeader and SwipeLayout

Tags: java, android, listview

I have implemented [StickeyHeader](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders) (iOS like SectionHeaderView) and [AndroidSwipeLayout](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout) to list view. now i found that my list view setitemOnClickListner not working.

Adapter needed to extend `BaseSwipeAdapter` and implement `StickyListHeadersAdapter` to make it work. everything works fine but not itemClicklistner.

```
mainListView = (StickyListHeadersListView)findViewById(R.id.classMarkingListView);
mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Log.e("Clicked","List Item");
            }
        });
```

Comment: create an interface and clicklistner in header adapter

Answer (score 0):

I endedup using intent from adapter. and it worked.

on `generateView`

```
swipeLayout.getSurfaceView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ClassDetailView.class);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```